# How to set image canvas size?

Tags: samsung, images

When you rotate an image, you might also need to adjust the canvas size to avoid cropping or leaving blank spaces. All I want is to have a picture, expand the canvas to a new size, and have the original pic pinned to either the bottom, top, or centrally. The free open-source software GIMP has had this feature for decades, easy to use, free, with no confusion and no pain:

[image]

Now, is it true that Google Photos on Android cannot even increase the canvas size, making it effectively impossible to rotate a picture a number of degrees and keep the whole picture without being forced to try and trick the software into doing a simple task? I just wanted the simple task of increasing canvas size, "adding head space", or adding white space, or enlarging the canvas but not affecting the image size, for so long.

Answer (score 0):

I had to find a way with a separate app named [Photo Editor](https://www.iudesk.com/). After several hours of non-scientific guessing, searching, and random fuzz testing, it appears that the function named fit (at the far right of the menu in the app) with "Don't Enlarge" will resize the canvas.

[image]

Now the canvas is resized.